# How to check if two numbers are equal to each other with a tolerance of plus or minus 1

Tags: php, php-7

How to check if two numbers equal each other with a tolerance of + or - 1?

Right now I just have a straightforward comparison:

```
   if($value1 != $value2) return false
```

But due to rounding difference between the ways value1 and value2 are generated I need to have a tolerance of plus or minus 1. Having a bit of a brain fart as to how you would actually do this.

Comment: if (abs($value1 - $value2) > 1) return false;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$ab = $value1 - $value2;
echo $ab;
$abs = abs($ab);
if($abs <= 1){
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'not ok';
}
```

Comment: This works but ill probably go with what  squeamish ossifrage  suggested

Comment: It's the same thing. It's just written differently.